# My Javascript snippet doesn't work on WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a digital marketer learning how to code - so I'm a total beginner in programming.

I'm trying to add a Javascript code to one of my Wordpress HTML pages but it appears as text snippet instead.

I've tried to Google the issue but nothing works. I tried using window.onload to test but it didn't work also.

JQuery has been installed and I made sure it's loaded first before this Javascript snippet fires. What can be the reason for the lack of response?

[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFFfg.png)

I've left the code snippet in my website for your viewing: https://www.jftimes.com/blog/

These are the codes I added:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert('hey');
    console.log('ready!');
}

$(function() {
   //actual code I'm doing
    $('.vc_col-sm-12 vc_gitem-col vc_gitem-col-align-left').each(function(){
        var link = $(this).find('.vc_gitem-link vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-flat vc_btn3-color-juicy-pink').attr('href');
        $(this).content().wrap('<a href="'+ link + '"></a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: first thing to always check is errors thrown in browser console

Comment: I did check for errors in the console. No error at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all the code in the tag `<script>`.
Otherwise, the browser has it as plain text.

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    //actual code I'm doing
    jQuery('.vc_col-sm-12 vc_gitem-col vc_gitem-col-align-left').each(function() {
        var link = jQuery(this).find('.vc_gitem-link vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-flat vc_btn3-color-juicy-pink').attr('href');
        jQuery(this).content().wrap('<a href="'+ link + '"></a>');
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Plus I think in Wordpress it's jQuery instead of $

Comment: As @CodingYourLife says, you should use "jQuery" instead of "$" so your snippet does not collide with other libraries.

Comment: This is fine for now small scripts. For bigger projects it's better practice to send the javascript as a separate file. E.g.: `<script src="/scripts/makeLinks.js"></script>`, then make the script publicly available (without the `<script>` tag) as `http://yourwebsite/scripts/makeLinks.js`. (And you should probably set the `Content-Type` header to `text/javascript` or something like that.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying. 

I used a plugin called CSS & Javascript Toolbox, so you can choose you want to add Javascript (which will automatically appear within <script> </script> ) or CSS (within <style> </style>).

So that isn't the issue. 

I changed from $ to jQuery to address it but it didn't work as well.

So this is really strange. 

I'm aware I've to eventually transition to using an external Javascript file, but I'm just adding small snippets so I don't think it's necessary at this stage. Thanks anyway.